# font garamond without oldstylenumbers

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums, garamond

I have to use Garamond for my publishing house. Is there a way to use the package garamond without having the numbers in the oldstyle?

Here are the packages which I am using for pdflatex:

```
\documentclass[twoside,Numbers=Lining,3.5headlines,smallheadings,10.5pt,
               tocleft,idxtotoc,final]{scrreprt}
% Fonts for pdflatex:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{garamond}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literatur}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literatur}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\sodef\an{}{.1em}{.4em plus.1em}{.8em plus.1em minus.1em}
\newcommand{\mycohead}[1]{\cohead {\an{ #1}\parbox[t][2mm][t]{0pt}{}}}
\newcommand{\mycehead}[1]{\cehead {\an{ #1}\parbox[t][2mm][t]{0pt}{}}}
%----------------------
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[dvipsdoc]{rotating}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics}
\usepackage{exscale,latexsym}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{graphpap}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{europs}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{titlesec}
% page format
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose, twoside, paperheight=213mm, paperwidth=140mm, textwidth=108mm, textheight=172mm}
%----------------------
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{upgreek}
%\usepackage{array}
% caption italics
\usepackage[font={it}]{caption}
%----------------------
\usepackage[alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\begin{document}
\garamond
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{1 Einleitung}
\mycohead{Einleitung}
\chapter*{1 Einleitung
\\
\vspace{6pt}
\mbox{}
\\\mbox{}
\\\mbox{}
}
This is the basic header. The font seems to be the garamond font.
The numbers are: 123456789. But should be without the old style.
\ungaramond
\\
\\
From here: the garamond is ignored.
This is the standard font and the numbers are: 123456789
\\
\\
But the book has more than 2 hundred pages with thousands of numbers and therefore I need a global routine for avoiding old-style-numbers.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks), as I did in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: you should not use the ngerman package. It can cause strange side effects. Use the package babel with the ngerman option.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help with your question, `\usepackage{garamond}` doesn't seem to use Garamond with my setup, but instead some horribly old versions of Computer Modern. I just wanted to note that your `documentclass` options yield a number of warnings for me (MiKTeX 2.9): `smallheadings`, `tocleft` and `idxtotoc` appear to be obsolete, and `10.5pt` is unused, probably not a valid font size specification. Also, is there a reason you load the font package `lmodern` if you want to use Garamond in the end?

Comment: Where did you get the support files for garamond and the font itself? Complete your example with a small document body. Compile it with pdflatex and put the document, the resulting pdf and the log-file somewhere on the net for inspection.

Comment: Thanks for adding the document body. Generally, try to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), since your above sample contains many packages that are actually not connected to the problem. Also, please try to comment in the right places, e.g. place your answer to @Ulrike's comment here, similarly your sentence about `lmodern`. This is all to make your issue easier to solve and thus for you to get better and faster answers.

Comment: If you don't want old style number, you absolutely shall not use Garamond. Garamond in running text without text figures just looks ugly.

Comment: This may answer your questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141914/is-there-a-way-to-use-ebgaramond-with-lining-numbers-as-default-in-pdflatex

Answer (score 9):

[EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/index.html) is an excellent, full-featured (and open-source!) Garamond font with support for OldStyle and Lining numerals.

It even has a variant of OldStyle numerals to differentiate from small caps.

See [the specimen stylesheet](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/blob/master/specimen/Specimen.pdf?raw=true).

You will need to use `fontspec` (with either XeTeX or LuaTeX):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

Let's count: 1, 2, 3, 3.1415

\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining}}
Let's count: 1, 2, 3, 3.1415

\end{document}
```

[image: EB Garamond: OldStyle and Lining styles]

Comment: From the doc: "Commands \oldstylenums{...} and \liningnums{...} are defined to allow
for local use of old-style figures or lining figures, respectively.
Similarly, \tabularnums{...} and \proportionalnums{...} allow for local
use of monospaced or varying-width figures, respectively."

Answer (score 4):

I'm really not an expert here, but you could probably just use the mathdesign-package with urw-garamond (`\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}`) instead, since it produces normal numbers by default. (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/garamond/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to install urw-garamond but it does not work. I am using pdflatex due to some other constraints which I have to consider. I deleted lmodern. Does anyone know how to get normal numbers with my calibrations?

Comment: @fab: Unfortunately, you need to get the urw-garamond font separately, as I have just found out myself (it didn't work for me either :/). If you're using linux, you can get it via `getnonfreefonts garamond classico` (terminal). (or manually: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/garamond/)

Comment: @fab: Another solution: Just download the package from the above website (garamond.zip) and move the files from the folder garamond (in the archive) directly into the folder where your tex-file is located. This solution is a little bit messy (whereas portable), but for me, it works.

Comment: @Lustique: its so strange. I did the same with the garamond which i am using and it works. as soon as i am using your recommended folder it appears the message: urw-garamond.sty could not be found. i coppied all files from that folder to the folder with the tex document. Do i need a beside the usepacke another routine in the header?

Comment: @ulrike fisher: I used the garamond from the webpage: http://gael-varoquaux.info/computers/garamond/index.html

Comment: @fab: The garamond package you got has explicitly replaced the normal numbers by the oldstyle numbers. It will not work. You should install the urw garamond from CTAN (fonts/urw/garamond.zip). It doesn't contain a sty. You should do `\renewcommand\rmdefault{ugm}` to use them or use `mathdesign`. (Don't forget to add the map file either with `\pdfmapfile{=ugm.map}` only in your document or with `updmap(-sys)` for the system.)

Answer (score 1):

I use the package `xagaramon`, which only generates old style figures if you pass it the `osf` option.  But there are so many different typefaces named garamond I am not entirely sure from your question whether we are talking about the same one.  I'm using Adobe Garamond Pro, which (for my perhaps idiosyncratic installation which dates about 10 years back) involves the prefix `pad` for all its files (e.g. I have the file `pad.map` in my texmf tree; you can use `kpsewhich pad.map` at the command line to check for this).

(Also, URW Garamond is more or less unrelated to Adobe Garamond, as far as I could tell when I looked into using those support files; they certainly don't involve interchangable .sty files.)

Comment: oops, I just spotted the comment saying that you are using a modified URW garamond.  I'll leave my answer since it hopefully clarifies things for other people, but given that, it probably doesn't help you, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the `garamond` package, load `ebgaramond` with the `lining` option.  To also get good math support, comment out the `newtxmath` line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
%\usepackage[ebgaramond]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
 1234567890 \oldstylenums{1234567890}
\end{document}
```

[image: lining figures]

It's possible to get the same effect (so `ebgaramond` with math support) with a single `usepackage` line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ebgaramond,lining]{newtx}
\begin{document}
 1234567890 \oldstylenums{1234567890}
\end{document}
```