# Is there a way to use ebgaramond with lining numbers (as default) in pdflatex?

Tags: numbering, pdftex, ebgaramond

Is there a way to use `ebgaramond` with *lining numbers* as default in `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond} %% you can also use nf or lf
\begin{document}
123456789
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the README file in the distribution of `ebgaramond`:

> This is the README for the ebgaramond package, version 0.15 (2013-05-22).
>
> This package provides LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX support for
>   the EB Garamond family of fonts, designed by Georg Duffner.
>
> EB Garamond is a revival of the 16th century fonts designed by Claude
>   Garamont. The source for the letterforms is a scan of a specimen known
>   as the "Berner specimen", which, composed in 1592 by Conrad Berner,
>   son-in-law of Christian Egenolff and his successor at the Egenolff print
>   office, shows Garamont's roman and Granjon's italic fonts at different
>   sizes. Hence the name of this project: Egenolff-Berner Garamond.
>
> Currently only upright and italic variants in medium weight are available.
>
> To install this package on a TDS-compliant TeX system unzip the
>   file `tex-archive/install/fonts/ebgaramond.tds.zip` at the root of an
>   appropriate texmf tree, likely a personal or local tree. If necessary,
>   update the file-name database (e.g., `texhash`). Update the font-map files
>   by enabling the Map file `EBGaramond.map`.
>
> To use, add
>
> ```
>    \usepackage{ebgaramond}
> ```
>
> to the preamble of your document. Options include:
>
> `oldstyle`,`osf`    old-style figures
>   `lining`,`nf`,`lf`    lining figures
>
> `proportional`,`p`  varying-width figures
>   `tabular`,`t`       fixed-width figures
>
> The defaults are `oldstyle` and `proportional`.
>
> Available shapes include:
>
> `it`              italic
>   `sc`              small caps
>   `scit`            italic small caps
>
> Slanted variants are not supported; the italic variants will be
>   automatically substituted. Font encodings supported are OT1, T1, LY1 and
>   TS1.
>
> Options `scaled=<number>` or `scale=<number>` may be used to adjust
>   fontsizes. The `type1` option may be used by `xelatex` or `lualatex` users
>   who prefer to use type1 fonts or to avoid `fontspec`.
>
> Commands `\oldstylenums{...}` and `\liningnums{...}` are defined to allow
>   for local use of old-style figures or lining figures, respectively.
>   Similarly, `\tabularnums{...}` and `\proportionalnums{...}` allow for local
>   use of monospaced or varying-width figures, respectively.
>
> Superior numbers (for footnote markers) are available using `\sufigures`
>   or `\textsu{...}`. Swash italic glyphs (for some letters) are available
>   using `\swshape` or `\textsw{...}`.
>
> Command `\textin{...}` produces decorative initials; currently
>   only the following glyphs are available: A, D, F, G, L, N, O, Q, T and X.
>
> A configuration file for microtype usage is included.
>
> The original fonts are available at
>   http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/ and are licensed under the SIL
>   Open Font License, (version 1.1); the text may be found in the doc
>   directory. Font charts may be found in the doc directory.
>
> The type1 versions were created using cfftot1. The support files were
>   created using autoinst and are licensed under the terms of the LaTeX
>   Project Public License. The maintainer of this package is Bob Tennent
>   (rdt at cs.queensu.ca)