# Garamond font issue with numbers

Tags: numbering, ebgaramond

I am using ebgaramond package to generate my document in Garamond font style but I have an issue that the numbers are not produced in a nice look

Here is my code

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}

{
\setmainfont{Arial}
Arial Font Here
}


Garamond Font Here

Random numbers: 01837334


\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Note that I compile using lualatex. Any help ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141917/134144 may be useful.

Comment: I think that the question is a duplicate: an other related is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21886/font-garamond-without-oldstylenumbers

Comment: These are simply oldstyle figures. If you don't want them, load the package  with option `[lining]`.